# ken wheeler's slick carousel down start normally with jquery steps

Tags: slick.js, jquery-steps

Sorry for my broken english.
I'm using ken wheeler [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) with [jquery steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/).
I add a new step with jquery steps like this:

```
$("#wizard").steps("add", { title: data.title, content: '<div id="slickdemo3"">'+data.content+'</div>' });
```

after that, I use slick script and starting slick function like this:

```
$('#slickdemo3').slick({     infinite: false,slidesToShow: 4,slidesToScroll:4});
```

adding step is succesfully done, but slick don't display normally, display like this: 
jsfiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/cw38qpc5/ 
[image]

but I start slick with javascript setTimeout function slick start and display succesfully.

like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('#slickdemo3').slick({     infinite: false,slidesToShow: 4,slidesToScroll:4}); }, 1000);
```

It is normal.
jsfiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/raowd335/ 
[image]

thanks for our advice sorry for my english again.

Comment: Please add a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) example!

Comment: it is jsfiddle without settimeout dont display true: https://jsfiddle.net/cw38qpc5/, it is with settimeout, display succesfully: https://jsfiddle.net/raowd335/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there isn't an event for dynamically added or removed steps so far, you have to use the `onStepChanged` event instead to initialize the inner component (e.g. *slick*) properly.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cw38qpc5/4/) you will find the modified jsfiddle you provided.